# $compile stripping inner contents of manipulated tags in IE

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Background**

I created a simple directive for my current project to basically create a simple nested list in a navbar (click to expand more options, click again to close). The idea was to remove all of the overhead of having to write setup code every time one of these was used and have the directive recompile itself with all of the angular components by finding the structural pieces, adding the necessary angular attributes, then reinjecting them into the container.

**The Problem**

In IE (not Edge), I found that the lists wouldn't render at all, and after a great deal of debugging narrowed my problem down to $compile. Basically, after the elements are manipulated, running them through $compile destroys everything inside of the tags. I've written up a basic example. I tested using this in IE 11 and got the described behaviour.

http://codepen.io/DAquilina/pen/PWRzjB

*problem area*

```
var injection = $(element).find ('> div');
$(injection).attr ('ng-if', 'true');
$(element).html ('');
$(element).append ($compile (injection) ($scope));
```

**The Question**

My question is in two parts:

1) Is the problem I'm describing happening for the reason I surmised, or is it something else that I missed?

2) What can I do to circumvent this problem while still maintaining the level of code abstraction I described above?

---

Re: `I'm pretty sure you can supply the template for a directive via a function. Why are you doing it this way instead? Also, what happens if you don't set the html for the element to an empty string?`

It's not the same content every time. In the case of my dropdown, you might have something like this:

```
<li util-dropdown>
  <a href>
    Services
  </a>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/foo>Foo</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/bar">Bar</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

And that would get compiled into:

```
<li util-dropdown class="util-dropdown">
  <a href ng-click="utilDropdownToggle ()">
    Services
  </a>

  <ul util-slide-transition-helper ng-if="!!utilDropDownExpanded">
    <li>
      <a href="/foo>Foo</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/bar">Bar</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

So yes, it's not a ton of extra stuff to write every time, but I'd rather the HTML be clean than not. As for the second part of your question, that might fix my problem, though I'm not sure why. Looking into it.

**UPDATE**: Pen has been updated with the suggested use case, and it works fine in all browsers. If someone could explain the behaviour on a deep, technical level I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can supply the template for a directive via a function. Why are you doing it this way instead? Also, what happens if you don't set the html for the element to an empty string?

Comment: Responded above. I have some research to do.

Comment: It works! If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Just to be clear, what you changed is not setting the html to an empty string?

Comment: I did that and I removed the append operation since it actually didn't do anything.

Comment: I think you should write up the answer, since you know what you did and why it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, a solution was found thanks to a helpful suggestion by [@Amy Blackenship](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854556/amy-blankenship).

**Original Problem Code**

```
var injection = $(element).find ('> div');
$(injection).attr ('ng-if', 'true');
$(element).html ('');
$(element).append ($compile (injection) ($scope));
```

**Updated Code**

```
var injection = $(element).find ('> div');
$(injection).attr ('ng-if', 'true');
$compile (injection) ($scope);
```

**So what changed?**

My newfound understanding of how $compile works is that the element gets angularized inline, not locally. What this means is that running $compile in the given scope does not clone and return the result of the operation, but instead changes the referenced element as it existed prior to the operation. In my example above, I'm selecting an element that already exists on the page, so when I clear the HTML it gets destroyed in the DOM while the reference to it still exists in my code, and when it's re-injected there's a conflict that IE doesn't really know how to rectify. Running $compile on the element directly without the DOM manipulation step bypasses this conflict.

In the case of examples 1 and 2 in the pen, the element that's getting manipulated was never on the page to begin with, so the reference is already local and as such no conflict exists when it gets injected into the page. In fact, I could inject it before the compilation step and it would still work.

*Note*: If debugging in similar circumstances, one of the things I noticed during my tests is that if I included some logging statements for the target element before the call to $compile, the output still contained the post-compiled element, which really threw me off.